# How to make the distinction between different exceptions in Netty's onChannelFailure callback

Tags: java, netty

I am writing an HTTP client with Netty 4.1.12.Final and I have unit tests simulating the crash of the HTTP server in order to be able to handle it.
I noticed that, when it happens, the exceptionCaught callback method of my inbound handler is called with:

```
java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1100)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:372)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:123)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
```

Where the english equivalent of the exception message is quite probably:

```
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Since this callback method is also called when an exception is thrown from my channelRead0 method of my inbound handler, I am asking a few questions:

- Should I always consider an IOException "received" in the exceptionCaught callback as an indication that there is no point in continuing using the channel?
- Since channelRead0 is declared to throw Exception, should I catch all IOException inside it in order to be sure that, when "receiving" an IOException in the exceptionCaught callback, it is related to the Channel?
- Is there a way to know if an exception "received" in the exceptionCaught callback is related to I/O operations or to handlers operations?

Thank you for any hint!

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I receive that IOException: ctx.channel().isActive(), isOpen(), isRegistered() and .isWritable() are all "true"

Answer (score 0):

1) If we are talking about a TCP connection then yes every IOException will result in having the connection closed automatically by netty as there is no way to recover.

2) I think I don't understand the question completely as each exception passed through the `exceptionCaught(...)` method is related the the channel which can be obtained by `ctx.channel()`

3) No there is no way in general. That said if its a TCP connection and its an IOException and its triggered by the actual transport we will close the connection.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am talking about a TCP connection. So because ctx.channel().isActive(), isOpen(), isRegistered() and .isWritable() are all "true"inside exceptionCaught, it means that the channel is actually closed after exceptionCaught being called?